# Уникальный текст - первоисточник

Tags: индексация

Распознаёт ли google и yandex поиски сайт, которые разместил первым определённый текст? Т.е. если сайт-вредитель скопировал у вас текст и разместил на какой-то промежуточный сайт для вреда, то пострадает ли сайт, который первым опубликовал его?

Comment: Что значит "пострадает сайт"?

Comment: Не пострадает, иначе таким образом можно было бы массово валить конкурентов, что вызвало бы бурю негодования. Какие существуют типы санкций от Google и Яндекс, и про их подробности см. [**здесь**](http://www.pixelplus.ru/samostoyatelno/stati/prodvizhenie-saytov/sanktsii-poiskovykh-sistem.html).

Comment: спасибо!!! да, логично...и спасибо за ссылочку